# How did the misconception about tendinopathies being a largely inflammatory condition appear?

Tags: tendinopathy, tendinitis, history, inflammation

As (1) reminds us, tendinopathies were commonly misdiagnosed as having a largely inflammatory condition before ~2005-2010. How did this myth appear in the first place?

---

- (1) Bhopal, Raj. "Time to abandon the “tendinitis” myth." Bmj 324 (2002): 626-7.; http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1122566/

> Tendinitis such as that of the Achilles, lateral elbow, and rotator cuff tendons is a common presentation to family practitioners and various medical specialists.1 Most currently practising general practitioners were taught, and many still believe, that patients who present with overuse tendinitis have a largely inflammatory condition and will benefit from anti-inflammatory medication. Unfortunately this dogma is deeply entrenched. Ten of 11 readily available sports medicine texts specifically recommend non-steroidal anti-inflammatory drugs for treating painful conditions like Achilles and patellar tendinitis despite the lack of a biological rationale or clinical evidence for this approach.2,3

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.